# Need to write a letter to manager for project allocation

Tags: manager, cover-letter

"I have been released from my project with effect from 1st Aug’16. Now I’m expecting  some challenging project in SQL Server/ SSIS. My first preference would be SQL SERVER. Also looking for some onsite opportunity."

Above is the message I want to convey to my manager. Things can be achieved easily if we approach it correctly. Now im trying to approach my manager, but im not satisfied with my words. Please help me out to covey the above message politely

Comment: Related: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/71170/is-it-rude-to-email-a-coworker-that-i-expect-him-to-do-something

Comment: already spoken to him and he is ok with me.. he wants me to write a formal letter. conversation happened in my own language but i'm bad in writing in english

Answer (score 3):

When I read that draft, pretending to be your manager:   I don't know what you're saying. I don't know what you are asking me to *do.* You haven't phrased it in a way that I can *act upon.*

Does not the person whom you are addressing already know that you have been or will be released from your current project? So, exactly why are you making this communication? What do you intend to say to me, and what do you intend to achieve?

When you say, *"I am expecting,"* did you mean to say, *"I am **asking** for?"* Are you saying that you believe that, of all the many projects in my in-basket that I could next assign you to, there's a particular reason why I would be wise to choose for you a project that involves SQL Server? "Then, say *that."* Use "action words."

Simply re-phrase your note as a *reminder* (if you think a reminder is necessary), followed by an *actionable request.* A request that makes it clear both why you are asking and what *action* you are requesting on my part.

My reply would then perhaps sound non-commital: *"Thank you for telling me this. I will take it under consideration."*